# is there an explicit interface declaration for abstract methods?

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

i have a (quite easy) problem and it seems I can't find out how to do it. I would appreciate some help.

I have two classes which are something like this:

```
public class FileParameters { ... }

public abstract class File {
    ...
    public abstract FileParameters Params { get; }
}
```

From both classes I have a derived special version:

```
public class SpecialFileParameters { ... }

public abstract class SpecialFile {
    ...
    private SpecialFileParameters params;
    public override FileParameters Params { get { return params; } }
}
```

When I want to use the SpecialFileParameters I have to cast them first, e.g:

```
((SpecialFileParameters)SpecialFileObject.Parameters).DoSomething();
```

which is quite obnoxious. What I would like to have is basically the same syntax as with interfaces

```
public abstract class SpecialFile {
    ...
    private SpecialFileParameters params;
    private override FileParameters File.Params { get { return params; } }
    public new SpecialFileParameters Params { get { return params; } }
}
```

But like this i get an compiler error: 'File' in explicit interface declaration is not an interface. Is there some other way to do this?

Some further information:

- I cannot change the base classes, only my special classes
- I actually need 2 special derived classes, one is written in C#, the other in C++/CLI. If the "trick" to makes it work is different between C# and C++ CLI please let me know.

Thanks for your help (and patience I guess ^^),

Answer (score 2):

It is somewhat different in C++/CLI, example of explicit overriding:

```
public ref struct BaseClass abstract
{
    virtual int Func(int) abstract;
};

public ref struct DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    virtual int BaseFunc(int x) = BaseClass::Func { return x + 2; }
    virtual int Func(int y) new { return y / 2; }
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    DerivedClass^ d = gcnew DerivedClass();
    BaseClass^ b = d;
    System::Console::WriteLine("4 ->  Base   -> " + b->Func(4));
    System::Console::WriteLine("4 -> Derived -> " + d->Func(4));

    return 0;
}
```

Marc has shown what you need to do for C#: use an additional layer of inheritance.

Comment: Explicit overriding isn't really relevant to the question in my opinion (i.e., the question asked for the wrong thing). I think what the OP *really* wants is covariant return types, which are not supported in C++/CLI (see C2392), and as far as I know are not supported in C# for abstract classes (as opposed to interfaces).

Comment: @ildjarn: Explicit overrides are a less-than-perfect workaround for the lack of covariant return.  Plus, the description of that error message isn't accurate.  The error message itself is correct: covariant return is not allowed in managed types.  But the description says it isn't allowed when compiling with `/clr`, whereas the actual behavior is that covariant return is allowed for native types regardless of `/clr` being set.

Comment: Apologies -- was tired and misread what the code was attempting to do. Edited so I could remove downvote.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no syntax in C# for marking an explicit abstract override method (as distinct from another method with the same signature), and since you can't have two matching signatures declared in the same level you can't do quite what you want.

Since you've ruled out changing the base class, the only suggestion I have is to add an artificial extra level:

```
public abstract class File {
    public abstract FileParameters Params { get; }
}
public abstract class FileIntermediate : File
{
    public override FileParameters Params {get { return ParamsImpl; }}
    protected abstract FileParameters ParamsImpl { get; }
}
public class SpecialFile : FileIntermediate
{
    public new SpecialFileParameters Params { get { return null; } }// TODO 
    protected override FileParameters ParamsImpl {get { return Params; }}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use generics to solve this:

```
    public class FileParameters   {    }

    public class SpecialFileParameters : FileParameters{}

    public abstract class File<T>
        where T : FileParameters
    {
        private T _params;

        public T Params   { get { return _params;}        }
    }

    public class SpecialFileParams : FileParameters<SpecialFileParameters> { }
```

and you will get the concrete "Special" when you access Params.

Comment: @bitxwise I missed that part.. 
In that case there's no way to avoid the cast.
You can use a separate getter with a different name to get the typesafe version, but if you are restricted to the getter defined in the abstract base then that's the contract you are bound to...

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to have the same method name between the two methods (the override and the new method)?  In these situations, I usually create a new method with a new name that returns the more derived type, and then have the override call this method in its implementation:

```
public override FileParameters Params { get { return SpecialParams; } }     
public SpecialFileParameters SpecialParams { get { return params; } }
```

In this way, when you have a SpecialFile object, you don't need the cast.  IF this doesn't work, perhaps you could explain more why you need the names of the methods to be the same for your situation.